# How to use WebPack to concat multiple html files into one

Tags: html, npm, webpack

To keep everything clear and easy to maintain, I have multiple html files (as HTML sections) in a folder like this:

```
htmls/
 - header.html
 - section1.html
 - section2.html
 - footer.html
```

Is there any way to combine these files into one html file like as `index.html` with WebPack 5?

I couldn't find any solution to do this.